# Image is not displayed

Tags: php

I am trying to display records with Images. I carefully named each image (1.png, 2.png, etc.) and placed them in the root folder. It should represent PRIMARY KEY of the record that I want to display.
Here is the code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DeptNo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['DeptName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Location'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><img src="'. $row['DeptNo']. '.png' . '"></td></tr>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

**Please note the Column ID is just for the  representation view, the real column is still DeptNo**

However, when I run it the images are not displayed. Where did I go wrong? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table says the ID is `Dn`, and not `n` (where `n` is the number), but your images say `n.png`.

Comment: The MySql column name is DeptNo, is just to look nice I changed to ID

Comment: Point remains. Your DeptNo doesn't look like your file name.

Answer (score 1):

You named images as 1.png, 2.png BUT image you posted shows your ID as D1, D2 etc.

I think here is the problem and you must also double check that relative path is correctly given in src attribute.

And also replace your that particular line with more elegant way.

> ```
> echo '<td><img src="'. $row['DeptNo']. '.png"></td></tr>';
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should enter an image format. In your case

```
echo $row['DeptNo'].".png"; // Your Image format.
```

this really should work otherwise you might have a query mistake.